Why doesn't Captain Pike get security guys skilled in hand to hand combat?
In Star Trek (2009), why does Captain Pike ask for officers skilled in hand-to-hand combat from the bridge instead of getting personnel from security to do the job? Why take Sulu away from his important position of flying the ship? What was the rush? He couldn't wait two minutes for some security personnel to meet him on the shuttle?

This question could easily be changed to In star trek why do bridge personnel perform away missions instead of a specialized away team?

@Questor simple - FIELD TRIP!!!

Security staff in this era are primarily enlisted crew. They're certainly drilled in combat operations but Pike needs a lot more than just that. He's after three people who have the mix of skills required to insert onto a swinging platform from orbit, access its controls, plant explosive charges and, if needs be, do this while defending themselves from hostile troops (hence the need for combat training).
That means he needs officers who've been through Starfleet Academy training and can hold their own in a melee fight.

With the aid of shuttlebay technicians, the three men struggled into the semiflexible dropsuits. Lightweight and fashioned of special composites nearly impervious to heat, the suits would keep them from turning into slender human-shaped cinders as they made the plunge into Vulcan’s atmosphere.
At least, Kirk told himself as he waited for a tech to hand him his helmet, that was how it worked in Academy simulations.
Where a suitable planetary surface was available and shuttle or transporter was not, space drop was designed to provide a final opportunity to escape a fatally crippled ship. It was strictly a last-gasp maneuver, akin to jumping off a sinking watercraft with nothing more than an antique life preserver. Everything they would need to survive the drop was integrated into the suits. A gleeful Olson took responsibility for the powerful charges that would be used to destroy the drill housing once they landed on it.
Star Trek: Official Novelisation


Could you clarify what the quote (which is presumably from the novelization of this specific movie, right?) adds to the answer? I don't quite get the relevance as it seems to just be Krik's internal monologue about the mission but nothing about requiring or even anticipating the need for combat skills.

@terdon - It highlights the other skills required for the mission (orbital drops, explosives etc), not just the combat abilities

@Valorum All of which are more likely to be had (orbital drops, explosives, etc...) by an enlisted person then a bridge officer... Orbital drops, explosives, hand to hand combat are an extremely diffferent skill set then the skills required to fly a spaceship.

@Questor - As you can see from the linked novelisation, it's clear that Starfleet officers train in orbital drops, hacking, interfacing with alien tech, etc etc. A security officer probably wouldn't have any of those skills and may not have even attended the Academy at all.

@Valorum I agree with Questor because both history and Hollywood tell us endless times that all the qualities listed belong to technical specialists, not to any officer.
Did no-one else notice, one of Star Trek's worst failings is that bridge officers in general and captains in particular are happy to skip off on every away mission that comes their way?
Did no-one notice, captains skipping off on away missions would be tantamount to dereliction of duty, and in the face of an enemy, deserting their posts?

@RobbieGoodwin The out of universe explanation for this... Is that it is both cheaper (less cast members) and better for audiences to have the bridge crew also be the away team.. than it is to have a dedicated away team.
The in universe explanations are justifications for the out or universe reasons.

@Questor  If that were true, it would be no excuse.
It doesn't need fewer cast members… just better writing. Oops!
With better writing, why waste the bridge crew on away teams, even if that was within the rules?
Doesn't that simply mean it's unlikely any senior away-team member will be hurt, let alone killed?
I see either dedicated or scratch-built away teams as clearly better in every way.
What do you really doubt about that?

@RobbieGoodwin - The MACOs made a lot of sense from an in-universe perspective, but were difficult to include in storylines and to write for.

@ Robbie Goodwin When redshirts die... no one cares. But when Spock or Kirk gets in trouble people care... It is good writing.
Remember the original series was written on a budget full of shoestrings and paper scraps.

@Valorum, et al  What's a MACO, please?

@RobbieGoodwin - They were the armed goons that were added to the cast of Enterprise when they went searching for the Xindi

@Questor  Have you really been so deluded for so many years?
If when redshirts die, no one cares, that's clear evidence of poor writing. Oops!
If people care solely because it's Spock or Kirk getting into trouble, that's more evidence of poor writing. Oops!
How could the original series being written on a budget full of shoestrings and paper scraps matter?

@Valorum  Thanks and are whichever episodes feature MACO available in my UK?

@RobbieGoodwin ...... I was being brief let me elaborate. People only care about the death of a fictional character if they have an emotional connection. In order to  have an emotional connection with someone you have to know who they are... Which takes more time than a single short tv episode. Hence why no one cares about some random red shirts dying.. .So it is good writing practice to use characters that the audience cares  about... Instead of random red shirts.

@Questor  Carry on thinking that way, and you carry on defending poor writing. Please don't do that!

As Kirk once told Krako "There're over 400 guys up there". If so, why not use them? It's always the same 7 people. What do the other 393 people do on board, water the plants? In season 1, sometimes they'd beam down an expert in whatever they were dealing with. By season 3 it was the Kirk, Spock and McCoy show. It irks me seeing them beam on a strange planet. It's a tv show written for the main characters, but why send the chief staff down to places where their services aren't need? Hell, they would've had Captain Kirk leading the Omaha beach raid in Normandy...with Scotty at his side.
